# trouble integrating paypal credit card payment

Tags: php, paypal

I have setup express checkout on a php custom site for payments. Basically it shows me the classic screen of paypal with the order summary and the "choose a way to pay" options.

How do I detect which one the user has clicked on? Paypal option or "pay with a credit card" option, so that I would either do a DoExpressCheckout or a DoDirectPayment NVP API call?

I've been using the code from [here](http://www.saaraan.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php) (Saraan's site) to use the token for paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Express Checkout, regardless if the buyer selects to log in with their PayPal account and make the payment, or select the guest checkout and pay with a credit card on PayPal pages you would still use the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API to complete the payment.  You would not need to do the DoDirectPayment API call.  This call would be used if you were setting up a payment page directly on your site, and did not want the buyer to leave your site to enter in their credit card information.

Comment: Yes, but what variables do I process from there? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: You can find the list of variables you need to passover listed on our developer.paypal.com site at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/ as well as in our developer docs https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf starting on page 94